# Using ng-repeat with dynamic value

Tags: html, angularjs

I have HTML that is rendered based on loaded metadata. It ends up forming a table of data based on a scoped value in the controller.

In the controller:

$scope.arrayOfCustomObjects = [{ entry: data1 },{ entry: data2 }];

The metadata is contained in a .json file, with the following format (I added two here, in reality there are hundreds, each one basically ends up describing an HTML element):

```
loadedMetaData:

{
    "field_1": {
        "index": 0,
        "type": "selectbox",
        "nameId": "arrayOfCustomObjects" <-- this is the string name of a scoped variable in a controller.
      },
    "field_2": {
        "index": 1,
        "type": "textinput",
        "nameId": "textField"
     }
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in loadedMetaData>
    <div ng-repeat="item in field.nameId">
         <!-- build out HTML for each -->     
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run this, it doesn't work (it never iterates over $scope.arrayOfCustomObjects). If I add a line to display {{field.nameId}} is displays 'arrayOfCustomObjects' but I think it's just the string, not the value it represents.

If I change the HTML to this it does work:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in loadedMetaData>
    <div ng-repeat="item in arrayOfCustomObjects">
         <!-- build out HTML for each -->     
    </div>
</div>
```

...but is there any way to keep the abstraction I'm going for? I'd like to be able to define the target array in the metadata so I don't have to define the controller-specific names in the HTML itself.

Comment: Could you create an example at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gENGLe

Comment: you can return $scope.arrayOfValues instead of string arrayOfValues

Comment: Unfortunately since it's loaded as metadata, I can't use a function in the controller to return the actual array, I just did that to try and replicate the abstraction. The name of the array is loaded as part of a json file that doesn't know anything about any of the controllers.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I've implemented a similar thing for "dynamic" forms, with a `field` object that contained it's type like yours, but I appended and array with options to the `field` object in a property called `options` (an array of objects with `label` and `value`). 

The `type` property of the metadata plays an important role, right? If it's `"type": "selectbox"` then the `nameId` would refer to a array of options, right?

Comment: @FranciscoHanna that's it exactly, in fact in the real data the array of options is part of a selectbox field object like you describe.

Comment: In that case I think you can use a `ng-if` to check if `type == 'selectbox'`, then iterate over the options of this `field`. Could this work?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your `loadedMetadata` is like:

```
[
    "arrayOfCustomObjects",
    // other 'data' object keys
]
```

Then you could have an object like this that stores your actual data:

```
data = {
    "arrayOfCustomObjects": [
        // some items
    ]
}
```

Then, in the template you do:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in loadedMetaData>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data[field]">
         <!-- display the items in arrayOfCustomObjects -->     
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately the amount of data I'm actually dealing with is too large to do that. I pared it down for my example but in reality the array is large, and the objects contained in it are huge, also it's dynamic so I can't really code it into the metadata.

Comment: I don't think that my answer deals with your large amounts of data, that's a topic for other question I think. What you mean by "I can't really code it into the metadata"? You don't know what the `loadedMetada` object looks like? Could you update your question and put a sample of what the `loadedMetadata` object looks like?

Comment: I added a better example of the metadata...I'm trying to keep it simple as not to throw too many variables in there. In reality those entries each have a ton of properties, but for my purpose here I'm trying to use 'nameId' as a sort of pointer to a scoped variable in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This takes the value as string

```
var field = { "nameId": "arrayOfCustomObjects" }
```

change this to

```
var field = { "nameId": arrayOfCustomObjects }
```

Comment: that would indeed create an array of objects, but it wouldn't be the same one as is bound on `$scope`.....

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but that field definition is actually inside a loaded json file, not a controller...the json file has no reference for the unquoted arrayOfCustomObjects.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below changes from your plunker code

1. Using scope function to convert string to scope variable
2. Rendering that variable inside inner ng-repeat

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arrayOfCustomObjects = [1,2,3]
$scope.loadedMetaData = {
    "field_1": {
        "index": 0,
        "type": "selectbox",
        "nameId": "arrayOfCustomObjects" 
      },
    "field_2": {
        "index": 1,
        "type": "textinput",
        "nameId": "textField"
     }
}
 
  $scope.getVariable = function(val){
    return $scope[val]
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">

 <div>
      <div ng-repeat="field in loadedMetaData">
        <div ng-repeat="item in getVariable(field.nameId)">
    {{item}}
</div>
</div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XGLZzX

Comment: I deleted the plunker it's just causing confusion - I was just trying to replicate the abstracted array name. In reality the name is loaded as part of metadata from a json file that doesn't know anything about the contents of any of the controllers.

Comment: @monkeyWithAMachinegun, can you create plunker with all the variables - loadedMetaData,  arrayOfCustomObjects and other variables if any

Comment: if the metadata from jsonfile doesn't know from contents of controller, how it willreturning the rendering in ng-repeat..as it should be in $scope['variable name']

Comment: This might not even be possible, that's my question. I am trying to determine if I can get a variable name from meta data, and then use ng-model to tie it to the actual scoped value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) property accessor with the `this` keyword:

```
<div ng-repeat="(fieldKey, fieldValue) in loadedMetaData>
    <div ng-repeat="item in this[fieldValue.nameId]">
         <!-- build out HTML for each -->     
    </div>
</div>
```

From the Docs:

> It is possible to access the context object [($scope)] using the identifier `this` and the locals object using the identifier `$locals`.
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression Context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context)